# Submit a form via Ajax with Simple Form and Rails 4

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4.0.1, Simple Form and Bootstrap 3 to create a modal dialogue for creating a new record.  I'm trying to submit the form via ajax, but I am unable to do so.

I've added `:remote => true` to the form declaration, as well as to the submit button. Yet the request is still being sent via HTML POST, causing a full-page reload.

The form is created as:

```
<%= simple_form_for SomeClass.new, :authenticity_token => true, :remote => true, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>
```

And I've tried to create the submit button with:

```
<%= f.submit :data => {:remote => true}, :class => "control-button" %>
```

Neither of these work.  The generated HTML shows the proper `data-remote` attributes.  Yet elsewhere in my app, I've been using standalone links with `link_to` together with the `:data-remote => true` option, which work via ajax as expected.  Turbolinks is disabled. But I'm simply having trouble submitting the form with ajax.

Am I overlooking something?  What is a suitable alternative?

Comment: you trying `<%= f.submit :ok, :remote => true , :class => "btn btn-success btn-sm control-button" %>` this ? without `:data`

Comment: I have tried that--still is not submitting properly.  I'll test with a new app and see if a library or something is causing this problem.

Comment: have you tried specifying the method in the simple_form wrapper :method => 'get'. I have not worked with Rails 4 yet but I have many forms using simple_form_for and bootstrap 3 running on Rails 3. I just submit the data as a get request, respond with jSon and parse the data with jQuery